# Does the default data import supports configurable product?

Tags: magento2, import

Under the system->data transfer->import, is this feature supports configurable products import? I downloaded the sampledata link, there is no configurable product inside.

Comment: let me know the magento 2 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a configurable product and its two simple products then export the products csv. You will get to know which columns and rows are in configurable products.

It will be like this:

[image]

Comment: How do the images be imported? where should i place the images?

Comment: Upload the image files to the default folder for importing product images: pub/media/import

Comment: For you reference:- https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-import-all-products-with-images-magento-2.html

Answer (score 0):

I got annoyed by it too and figured out a way to do it, just not the importing of the attributes itself.

Make the attribute values -> Add a column with your Attribute code in the import doc -> Match the values with each other -> import

**Example:**
I made attribute with options that are sizes; "1 x 1mm, 1 x 2mm, 2 x 2mm," Attribute code is made_up_size

Now in the import doc just add another COLUMN with the same name you gave your attribute code, so mine is: made_up_size, with the rows below like:

- **row 1:** 1 x 1mm
- **row 2:** 1 x 2mm
- **row 3:** 2 x 2mm

etc